# i can't deploy changes in prisma schema probleme

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

I wanna add few changes to my schema and then deploy it but I keep getting a problem in the `id` field for some how I can't add `@unique` to it I tried to change the extension file to `.prisma` instead of `graphql` but it doesn't work at all

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  email: String!
}

type item {
  id: ID! @unique
  title: String!
  description: String!
  image: String
  loadImage: String
  price: Int!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updateAt: DateTime!
  # User:User!
}
```

Comment: Which version of prisma you are using?

Comment: i fixed the prob thanks bro